# Access from class MainActivity to variable from other class

Tags: java, android, camera

In class MainActivity I have no access to gamePanel variables or objects. From other classes later
in programm it works well.
I got following errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.camerademo3/com.example.camerademo3.MainActivity}:
Attempt to read from field 'java.util.ArrayList com.example.camerademo3.GamePanel.images2' on a null object reference
```

Class MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GamePanel gamePanel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //some code
        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

        //some code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        //some code

        if (requestCode == 100) {
            Bitmap captureImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            gamePanel.images.add(captureImage);  // no access here
        }

        //some code
    }
}
```

Class GamePanel:

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    //some code

    protected ArrayList<Bitmap> images;

    public GamePanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        images = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't storing your GamePanel anywhere.  I think you wanted to do

```
gamePanel = new GamePanel(this)
setContentView(gamePanel)
```

Otherwise when you reference gamePanel it will be null since you never set it.

Comment: Ok, I will check it

Comment: Still doesnt work, but this time (after adding `gamePanel = new GamePanel(this)`) the error is: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Probably solved